# Perform function on each level of multiple columns in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I need to perform a function on each level of multiple columns in a `data.table`. For example, using the `lung` dataset from `survival`:

```
library(survival)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

data(lung)
setDT(lung)

vars <- c("sex", "ph.ecog")
lung[, (vars) := lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols = vars]

fit <- tibble()
for (i in levels(lung[, vars ])){
temp <-
coxph(
  Surv(time, status) ~ i,
  data = lung
) %>% 
broom::tidy(exp=T)
fit <- bind_rows(fit, temp)
  }
```

This is not working - how can I succeed?

Comment: try removing the `%>% ` in the 4th row from the end. it doesnt work like this. save `coxph` in a new variable and then operate on it. it is not possible to `%>%` into an assignment operator like you did.

Comment: you are right, i edited it. but that doesnt solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to run the function for each level of `vars` column or for each `vars` column?

For the later, you can do :

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(vars, function(x) {
  broom::tidy(coxph(reformulate(x, 'Surv(time, status)'), data = lung))
}))

#  term     estimate std.error statistic   p.value conf.low conf.high
#  <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 sex2       -0.531     0.167     -3.18 0.00149    -0.859     -0.203
#2 ph.ecog1    0.369     0.199      1.86 0.0634     -0.0205     0.758
#3 ph.ecog2    0.916     0.225      4.08 0.0000448   0.476      1.36 
#4 ph.ecog3    2.21      1.03       2.15 0.0314      0.197      4.22
```

To simplify a bit since you are already using `data.table`, you can use `rbindlist` instead of `do.call` + `rbind`.

To run this for levels in your data you can do :

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(vars, function(x) do.call(rbind,
        lapply(levels(lung[[x]]), function(y) 
    broom::tidy(coxph(reformulate(x, 'Surv(time, status)'), 
            data = lung[lung[[x]] == y]))))))
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves the stated problem. However, I think I was clear enough. If, in another scenario, I wanted to perform a function on each _level_ of multiple columns, how could i perform this? I the case of a cox reg, this is redundant of course.

Comment: How will you run it for one iteration without any loop?

Comment: eg. survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog, data = lung[sex==1] ). Then, i would be interested in each level of "sex" and multiple other columns.

Comment: See updated answer, if it helps. Make sure that all the factor levels are present in your data.

Comment: I see this works using the coxph function, but not with the survfit function that i need:do.call(rbind, lapply(vars, function(x) do.call(rbind,
                                                lapply(levels(lung[[x]]), function(y) 
                                                  broom::tidy(survfit(reformulate(x, 'Surv(time, status)~ph.ecog'), 
                                                                    data = lung[lung[[x]] == y]))))))